# Click / place object in map and get a circular selecion around it

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im totally new to this, and I need some help.

I need to create an aviation range map. Look at the below link, and in the menu to the left theres a "Range maps".

I started with the Google Maps API Javascript V3, I thought it could be a good base to get rid of Flash.

Now I need some pointers for how I can either add an object to the map or just click in the map and that brings up a circle around the pointer with range for how far the aircraft can go.

I sure hope you understand, and can give me some pointers for how to start. Every tip is appreciated!

http://www.cessna.com/citation/citation-cj4/citation-cj4-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [Circle overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#BasicShapes), which is pretty easy to make. The docs have easy examples to follow.

You'll also want an onclick event for each overlay and for the map itself. That way whenever someone clicks on the map or on an overlay, it creates your circle. Check out the [events documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events).

Comment: Yeah, thats great! Thank you, I can start work with that! One other thing, in the above example they use population for the circle radius. Is there any way to change that value, for I need value to the range for wich the aircraft can go on one tank, i.e km radius.

Comment: The value is actually in number of meters. Population/20 was used to calculate how big the radius should be but you can just use meters directly.

Comment: As of now, I've successfully created a marker on the map with a circle around it. The problem is, that when the map/page loads the marker is already in a specific place, it is draggable tho. What I really want now is to remove the marker and make the user set the marker with a click. But when I add the click event, the marker appears where I click but the circle doesnt. Even tho they still are binded together..

Comment: This is the code, but it really just places the marker and no circle around it, but as I said if I hardcode a location for the marker from start the circle is there.

http://pastebin.com/CMuTsgza